# Android Studio import com.google.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile; does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to setup the apk expansion setup. I added the SampleDownloaderActivity.java but I am getting these errors once I rebuild the project

import com.google.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile; does not exist
import com.google.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile.ZipEntryRO; does not exist

What is the alternative to correct this?

Comment: you have to include the expansion library separately as the code dependency, you can get the relevant code at location `<sdk>/extras/google/google_market_apk_expansion/zip_file/`

Comment: @dinkar_kumar do you know what I can do with import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar; ? I get an error for that as well

Comment: if that helped could you please upvote and accept my answer?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: there is an answer below you have to accept that answer as the solution and you can upvote that using the up arrow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67361831/4828650 this is the link of the answer

Comment: this will help you know how to accept answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: regarding Snackbar, are you using androidX ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the expansion library separately as the code dependency, you can get the relevant code at location `<sdk>/extras/google/google_market_apk_expansion/zip_file/`